# NFS connection refused

Tags: nfs

I want to set up a filesharing server with NFS. But when I want to show the conetnts of export I get this:

```
manuel@server ~ $ showmount
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused)
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Horribly. I read about 5 Tutorials, but none of them mentioned that the service `rpcbind` is needed.

For Debian

```
sudo service rpcbind start
```

does the trick.

Comment: That does not solve the issue for me. If someone has any other suggestion, they are most welcomed!

Comment: Is this command run on the NFS server or NFS client.  You need to be explicit.

Comment: @Jim install/start this service on the NFS client

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

1. Remove the reject entry
2. Remove the forward entry
3. Save

From the command-line, type:

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT
 /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Restart the `rpcbind` service.

Run `showmount -e ipaddress` where "ipaddress" is the IP of your NFS server.

Comment: I have a server with three different interfaces.  Only one of which is allowed the rpcbind action.

`showmount -e` yielded the same error as shown by the original poster.

A slight modification, based upon the above, results in a command returning expected results:  `showmount -e 127.0.0.1`.  This forces to the local host, rather than one of the other interfaces.

Comment: Do you change the iptables on the nfs server or client?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I hope this will help other people. This is for Red Hat.

```
showmount -e server_address
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused)
```

Doing this produced a new error.

```
/sbin/service rpcbind start
showmount -e server_address
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Authentication error
```

This was the fix that got everything to work.

```
/sbin/service autofs restart
```